# How can I find the colour of any pixel on the screen

Tags: delphi, vb6, delphi-2009, c++builder

I usually program in VB6 but but I believe with that I might be restricted to details within the active form. I also  have codegear 2009 with c++ and delphi, that I got from a mate but I only have a little experience with Delphi and none at all with c++ but at least I have them if one of those program need to be used to acheive what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to do something like

```
IF pixelVar(x,y) = 'Red' ( or 'RGBvalue or whatever the correct colour representation)
THEN
    do something
END IF
```

I want to write a program to keep poker hand statistics and want the program to run while Im playing in the poker client program, auto recognizing the cards by pixel colour and position and entering them into the database. I think that if I can get easy access to pixel info it wouldn't be too difficult working out patterns to identify the number and suit of cards.
Any help would be enormous. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to rewrite the Poker game to automatically keep the statistics you desire (unless you've got your mind set on a particular game). I made a blackjack simulation once and I haven't been inside a casino since. ;-)

Comment: Writing an online poker bot eh?

Comment: "I also have codegear 2009 with c++ and delphi, that I got from a mate"? Sounds legit...

Comment: @Deanna, would you like to meet my mate Kim DotCom?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`GetDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871.aspx) with its `hWnd` parameter set to 0 to get an `HDC` handle for the screen, then use [`GetPixel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909.aspx) to get a [`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx) of the pixel at the desired screen coordinates, and then finally use [`GetRValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144923.aspx), [`GetGValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144893.aspx), and [`GetBValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144856.aspx) to split the `COLORREF` into its Red, Green, and Blue values.